# What happens to my ethics application when transferring PhD to a new uni?

Tags: phd, ethics, transfer-student

I may need to transfer my PhD to a new university soon due to moving overseas. My PhD can be done entirely online, so in theory this shouldn't hinder the research itself.

For my current project, I have already had my ethics application accepted by my current university, along with a substantial number of other documents (e.g. data management plan, data sharing agreement, etc). Will I need to repeat this documentation at a new university? I.e. will I need to redo my ethics application and data sharing agreement?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> will I need to redo my ethics application and data sharing agreement?

Yes. It's possible (but not particularly likely) that you will be able to expedite approval a bit if you've shown you went through the process before, but every institution is in charge of their own research program, and you're now going to be part of a different institution's program. If both you and a colleague at a different institution were involved in collecting data for the same project, you'd likely both need to get separate approval in that case, as well.

Hopefully most of the writing you've done can be used again, saving you some work, though different review boards may have different standardized forms they want you to use.

One way to think about this is that basically your old institution no longer has any sway over you, so they can't really hold you to anything. They can't fire you or prevent you from getting a degree or anything - your new institution can, so they're the ones that have jurisdiction over the work you do. In the US (other countries may be similar), the laws governing ethical research typically apply primarily to the institution: as a result of receiving government funds, the institution promises to comply with certain regulatory requirements, including ensuring that work done at their institution is performed according to certain ethical standards. Even if you were moving within the same country, the new institution would need to sign off on your work. It's even more unlikely that anything approved in another *country* could be considered ahead of time to comply with the local regulations.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the approach that Institutional Review Boards (IRBs) and Human Research Ethics Committees HRECs) take to approving research at universities tends to conflate *ethical behavior* with *institutional risk*.

As a consequence, a decision by a university to *approve* a research project should therefore usually be interpreted as a positive statement about *two separate issues*, one of which is general but the other, university specific. In particular, the approval probably implies that your research both conforms to generally accepted ethical standards of behavior and ***also*** does not expose your approving institution to unnecessary (or, for them, unacceptable) risk.

The problem is that if you then transfer to a new university, the new institution might well agree with the first university regarding the conformity of your research with accepted standards of behavior. However, they will almost certainly want to make their own assessment about the extent to which the research exposes them (i.e., the new institution) to risk. You are, as a result, almost certainly going to have to submit a new ethics application.

... As an academic, I'm just about to do the same thing myself!